# can't find gem rspec-core (>= 0.a) with executable rspec (Gem::GemNotFoundException) in VScode

Tags: ruby, rspec, rvm

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
        1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
```

Comment: We need more context than this. What command do you run, what VSCode has to do with it?

Comment: Try installing RSpec